# FileDialog doesn't find the method ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, filedialog

I'm learning C and C#, the question is for C#, I'm reading this programming book and this code is not compiling.

[image]

`FileDialog` is only showing two methods in intellisense(Equals and ReferenceEquals). The code is from a book so it is expected that this method and property are part of the `FileDialog` class right?

Here is the code:

```
    private void cmdBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e   
    {
        if (FileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            txtLocation.Text = FileDialog.FileName;
            cmdWatch.Enabled = true;
            FileDialog.
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I found out what the problem was, I hadn't added a filedialog to the form, I didn't know what a filedialog was, now I remember. Dohh

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question, rather than a screenshot of the code

Comment: Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you want an instance of a class, rather than using the class directly. However, [`FileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an abstract class which means you cannot instantiate it directly, but there are a couple of implementations that you can use...

Assuming you want to select (open) a file, then you can use [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if(dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    txtLocation.Text = dialog.FileName;
    cmdWatch.Enabled = true;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to choose a file location for saving then use [`SaveFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`FileDialog` is an abstract class. You have to use one of its implementations. Either `SafeFileDialog` or `OpenFileDialog` depending on your needs.

More information about the `FileDialog` class is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[`FileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the class, but you need an instance of it to open it. So presuming you are using a `OpenFileDialog` and it's name  is `OpenFileDialog1`:

```
if(OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    // ...
}
```

You normally create an instance by calling the constructor of a class, f.e:

```
OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
```

You can only call methods via classname that are `static`.